# My site is having a confilct with netlify after I deleted it

Tags: dns, netlify, nameservers

I have a  site, bemsinstitute.com which I tried to host using netlify via a custom domain.

After some time, I change my mind and decided to use the CPanel from the domain I got.

I removed the nameserver back to default and made sure I deleted the site and domain on netlify, now the issue is, I keep getting a "Site Not Found" error when I try to access my site which is now hosted on CPanel and the nameserver pointing to the default and not netlify nameserver.

This is weird to me cause the error indicates my site still has or having a conflict with netlify and it is frustrating me.

Has anyone had a similar issue?
How did you solve it?